# Independence of random variables X and Y

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, each taking the values $-1$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$, and let $Z = XY$. Show that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are pairwise independent. Are they independent?
This is my approach:
$P(X=-1,Z=-1)$= $1/4$ as $X=-1$ and $Z=-1$ is only possible if $Y=1$. Similaerly for others.
$P(X=-1,Y=-1,Z=-1)$=$0$, as $Z=XY$, so they are not independent, only pairwise.

Comment: Clearly, knowing any two determines the third.

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown is an example of $3$ random variables being pairwise independent but not all independent. I can give you an example  of $n$ dependent random variables amont which any $n-1$ of them are independent. Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in\{0,1\},\;(n\geq 3)\,$ satisfy

$$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=\mbox{even}.$$

Let $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ be any solution to the equation equally likely. Without the even sum condition, $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ has $2^n$ equally likely possible values. Knowing all values of $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ with no knowledge of $x_n$ does not change the $50$-$50$ distribution of the parity of $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n$ as $x_n\in\{0,1\}$ is equally likely to keep or change the parity of $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n-1}$. Of course, the odd sum condition $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=\mbox{odd}$ yields the same situation.

Examples of $\pm 1$ variables can also be constructed. Let random variables $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in\{-1,1\}$ satisfy $\,x_1x_2\cdots x_n=1\,$ (or $\,x_1x_2\cdots x_n=-1$).

Comment: Could you explain a little more for the case $n=2$ when $x_1+x_2 = \text{even}$ means that the only possibilities for $(x_1, x_2)$ are $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. How does knowledge that $x_1 = 1$ not affect the $50$-$50$ distribution of the unknown $x_2$? If I know that $x_1=1$ then I know that $x_2 = 1$ also because the only possibility is that $(x_1,x_2) = (1,1)$, no?

Comment: Maybe I should say $n\geq 3$, because for $n=2$, the $2$ variables are dependent but "any $1$ variable is independent" does not have any meaning. The argument still holds. Knowing $x_1$ or $x_2$ individually does not help reduce the uncertainty of the parity of $x_1+x_2$.